# How can I split a string with awk when FS is already in use?

Tags: awk

Let's say I have a `file.csv` as the following:

```
id;filename;device
1;118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101;
2;118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101;
3;118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101;DEVICE-0001-33
4;118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101;DEVICE-0001-33
5;118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101;DEVICE-0001-33
6;118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101;DEVICE-0001-33
7;118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101;DEVICE-0001-33
```

I've created an `awk` script for handling getting the device name when it appears on my file and then it finishes its execution. The `script.awk` is functional and is as the following:

```c
BEGIN {
    FS=";"
}
NR > 1 { fileName = $2 }
NR > 1 { if ( $3 != "" ) { device = $3; exit} }
END {
    if ( device == "" ) {
        line = "UNCONNECTED_"fileName".txt;UNCONNECTED"
    } else {
        line = device"_"fileName".txt;"device
    }
    print "filename;folder"
    print line
}
```

Its output after executing `awk -f script.awk file.csv` is:

```
filename;folder
DEVICE-0001-33_118574934-20220503-17h44m20s101.txt;DEVICE-0001-33
```

The problem is that I'd like to split the string `DEVICE-0001-33` into `DEVICE-0001`. Since I've already used `FS` with `;` and I can't use `FS` again as `-` in order to split my `device` variable. How can I handle that using only `awk`? How can I split a variable with a specific character once `FS` is already being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your case, using `sub()` seems enough. Instead of assigning `$3`, which is `DEVICE-0001-33`, to your variable, you want to use a substring of it. Assuming that `-` is the separator inside there, you  want to remove the last field.

```
echo "DEVICE-0001-33" | awk '{sub(/-[^-]*$/,"",$1); print}'

DEVICE-0001
```

We use `-[^-]*$` in order to get the last separator together with the last field. And not just `-.*$` because it's greedy and will eat all the fields but the first. The replacement is the empty string `""`. And the result is written to the field. So you can replace `device = $3` with

```
sub(/-[^-]*$/,"",$3); device = $3
```

---

The general answer to the title of your question is to use the `split()` function. It gives you the ability to treat a field or any string, like if it was a record, a line with fields, using a separator different than the `FS`. This example describes what it is doing:

```
echo "DEVICE-0001-33" | awk -v s='-' '{
    n=split($1,arr,s)
    print "number of fields: " n
    print "separator: " s
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print "field: " i " value: " arr[i]
}'

number of fields: 3
separator: -
field: 1 value: DEVICE
field: 2 value: 0001
field: 3 value: 33
```

And you can do on this string what awk can do for a line.

Comment: Thanks, using the regular expression looks more straightforward for sure. I think that in my specific case I'd have to create that for loop in order to join the string if I used the `split` function...

Comment: Yes, for operations like "remove the last field", "get only the first one" etc, `sub()` and `gsub()` are very handy. You would have to use `split()`, if you 'd like to re-order the sub-fields, or print them reversed, or get their number etc.